# How to retrive a doc from firestore with its ID with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I have a collection of **user_profile** in my app console. I want to retrieve a doc (a particular user profile with its user id [click to check][1]).

I know that *FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;* would give me the current login user ID but that is not what I want. I want to show the details of the clicked user, not the logged_in user, can't seem to find any answer here that was helpful. Please help guys

This is the method that gets the collection

```
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUserData() {
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    _firestoreInstance
        .collection('user_profile')
        .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      print(value.data());
      return value.data();
    });
  }
```

and here is my future builder

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getUserData(),
      // ignore: missing_return
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error fetching user profile');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> userData = snapshot.data.data();
          return Scaffold(
              body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Navigator.pushNamed(context, Homepage.id);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 70,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: Image.asset('assets/avatar_profile.jpg'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
                            radius: 25,
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "${userData['nickname']}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                        ),
                        VerticalDivider(
                          thickness: 3,
                          width: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          // '7',
                          "{$userData['age]}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.person,
                              size: 40,
                            ),
                            title: Text("About me"),
                            isThreeLine: false,
                            dense: true,
                            subtitle: Text("${userData['aboutMe']}"),
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 400,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          ProfileListTile(
                            leading: Icons.phone_in_talk,
                            title: 'Phone Number',
                            subtitle: "${userData['mobile']}",
                          ),
                          ProfileListTile(
                            leading: Icons.add_location,
                            title: 'Current Location',
                            subtitle: "${userData['location']}",
                          ),
                          ProfileListTile(
                            leading: FontAwesomeIcons.heartbeat,
                            title: 'Relationship Status',
                            subtitle: "${userData['maritalStatus']}",
                          ),
                          ProfileListTile(
                            leading: Icons.people,
                            title: 'Gender',
                            subtitle: 'Male',
                          ),
                          ProfileListTile(
                            leading: Icons.looks,
                            title: 'Interested In',
                            subtitle: "${userData['InterestedIn']}",
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this easily by just passing from usersCard to UserProfile (my bad, lolx), since I already have this data on list users screen, there was no need to fetching them again with *FutureBuilder*

```
class UsersCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Users usersDetails;

  const UsersCard({Key key, @required this.usersDetails}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
         UserProfile(userDetails: usersDetails))); //im passing the data here
        
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Card(
            semanticContainer: true,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            child: Image.network(
              'https://placeimg.com/170/170/any',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            elevation: 5,
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '${usersDetails.nickname}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  ),
                  VerticalDivider(
                    thickness: 2,
                    width: 20,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${usersDetails.age}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my UsersProfile Screen

```
class UserProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Users userDetails;

  UserProfile({@required this.userDetails});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // Navigator.pushNamed(context, Homepage.id);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 70,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Image.asset('assets/avatar_profile.jpg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
                        radius: 25,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${userDetails.nickname}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                    ),
                    VerticalDivider(
                      thickness: 3,
                      width: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      // '7',
                      "{$userDetails.age}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                          size: 40,
                        ),
                        title: Text("About me"),
                        isThreeLine: false,
                        dense: true,
                        subtitle: Text("${userDetails.aboutMe}"),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: 400,
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      ProfileListTile(
                        leading: Icons.phone_in_talk,
                        title: 'Phone Number',
                        subtitle: "${userDetails.mobile}",
                      ),
                      ProfileListTile(
                        leading: Icons.add_location,
                        title: 'Current Location',
                        subtitle: "${userDetails.location}",
                      ),
                      ProfileListTile(
                        leading: FontAwesomeIcons.heartbeat,
                        title: 'Relationship Status',
                        subtitle: "${userDetails.maritalStatus}",
                      ),
                      ProfileListTile(
                        leading: Icons.people,
                        title: 'Gender',
                        subtitle: 'Male',
                      ),
                      ProfileListTile(
                        leading: Icons.looks,
                        title: 'Interested In',
                        subtitle: "${userDetails.interestedIn}",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is currently not returning anything from `getUserData` yet. The only return you have is inside the `then` function, and doesn't escape to the higher level.

The simplest way to fix it is by using `await`:

```
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUserData() async {
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var doc = await _firestoreInstance
        .collection('user_profile')
        .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
        .get()
    return doc.data();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but this would get the current loggedIn userDetails. i want a user to be able to view other users details.

Comment: In that case you can pass in the UID of *that* user to the `doc()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like your app's users to see other people's profile.

To do that, you would first have to accept the `uid` of the user to display the profile. Then you can pass the uid to the future like the following example:

```
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfilePage({
    Key key,
    @required this.uid, // Here you are receiving the uid of the currently viewd user's uid
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String uid;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text('Error fetching user profile'));
      }
      final userProfile = snapshot.data;
      return Column(
        children: [
          // Here you would paste the contents of your user profile widget
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserData() async {
    final snap =
        await _firestoreInstance.collection('user_profile').doc(uid).get();
    return snap.data();
  }
}
```